# My ubuntu 18.04 apps stopped working after I downgraded my java

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, downgrade

I recently downgraded my java version from

> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

to

> java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

At the moment I have

```
user-admin@V0007054:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Since then almost all my apps including *IntelliJ*,*Rubymine* and *Slack* stopped working. I'm convinced that this happened after the downgrade. I uninstalled *IntelliJ* and reinstalled it (twice) through Ubuntu Software app again, but it still doesn't come up when I click on the app.

I did google it for a while but couldn't find any useful info about this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you see when you start IDE in the terminal, for example using `bin/idea.sh`? Note that IntelliJ IDEA uses the bundled runtime per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879 and system JDK should not affect it unless you've overridden it via the environment variable or you are using a version without the bundled JetBrains Runtime.

Comment: Why would you even down grade your java version. :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder I cannot even find it. I tried it with Rubymine, I can start it from the command line, but not by clicking on its icon.

Comment: @AliJ You may need to reinstall the desktop entry. Tools | Create Desktop Entry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how exactly to do that! I appreciate some instructions please.